# jqgrid data only loading some columns

Tags: coldfusion, jqgrid

jqgrid is only loading some of the columns.  I've not been able to find a pattern as to why some columns load while others do not.  When the column is edited, it does update the database.  The fields that do load will refresh when edited.  The first column, acresHarvested, does not show up.  There are others that do not show up, as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {

    jQuery("#prodgrid").jqGrid({

        url:'cfc/productionfacts.cfc?method=jqgridCP&cropprofileid=<cfoutput>#url.cropprofileid#</cfoutput>',

        width:"auto",
        height:"auto",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['Acres Harvested','ID','Production Year', 'USRank', 'US Acres', 'Acres Planted', 'Production', 'Production Value', 'productionCostsPerAcre', 'stateAvgPerAcre', 'natlAvgPerAcre', 'Price', 'Per Acre Value', 'Growers', 'Unit'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'acresHarvested',index:'acresHarvested', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'cpproductionfactid',index:'cpproductionfactid', search: true, editable:false, width:50 },
            {name:'productionyear',index:'productionyear', search: true, editable: true, width:150},
            {name:'usrank',index:'usrank', search: true, editable:true, width:50},
            {name:'USAcresPercent',index:'USAcresPercent', search: true, editable:true, width:50},
            {name:'acresPlanted',index:'acresPlanted', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'production',index:'production', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'productionvalue',index:'productionvalue', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'productionCostsPerAcre',index:'productionCostsPerAcre', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'stateAvgPerAcre',index:'stateAvgPerAcre', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'natlAvgPerAcre',index:'natlAvgPerAcre', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'price',index:'price', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'perAcreValue',index:'perAcreValue', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'growers',index:'growers', search: true, editable:true, width:100},
            {name:'unit',index:'unit', search: true, editable:true, width:100}
            ],
        jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "cpproductionfactid"},
        rowNum:10,
        rownumbers:true,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        sortname: 'productionyear',
        viewrecords: true,
        recordtext: "Record {0} - {1} of {2}",//Pager information to show
        sortorder: "desc",
        editurl:"cfc/productionfacts.cfc?method=editProdFact&cropprofileid=<cfoutput>#url.cropprofileid#</cfoutput>",
        caption:"Production Facts",
        pager: '#pager'
        });

        jQuery("#prodgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit: true, add: true, del: false, search: false}, 


            {closeAfterEdit: true}, 
            {closeAfterAdd: true}

            );

        jQuery("#prodid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
        //reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape: true,afterSubmit:processEdit,closeAfterEdit: true,closeAfterSubmit: true}

        jQuery("#prodgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOnEnter:false});


    });


</script>

<table id="prodgrid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have problem with **loading** of data then you should include the test data received from the server. It would be enough to include two rows of data. It's important to include **real data**. For example if the case of the names (like `acresHarvested`) is not exactly the same then it could be the problem. I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to make trace of HTTP traffic. I recommend you to move `<script type="text/javascript">` block from `<body>` to `<head>`. `$("document").ready(..)` inside of `<body>` looks strange.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  It turns out that CF JSON serialization was converting the fields to all lowercase.  I was using the letter case retrieved in the CF query in colModel rather than all lower case
JSON data: "usacrespercent":0,

ColModel:   {name:'USAcresPercent',index:'USAcresPercent', search: true, editable:true, width:50},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colModel names are case sensitive and need to match what the case of the JSON.  As stated in another response, Fiddler helps to view the returned JSON.